# Prove the function $3x^2-3x+1$ to be onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble proving $3x^2-3x+1$ to be onto Real numbers -> Real numbers.

Are there any guidelines to follow in this type of proof? I don't really know where to start

Comment: Onto what? ${}{}{}{}$ It isn’t onto the real numbers. Nor the positive real numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post - thanks

Comment: $3(x-\frac12)^2+\frac14\ge\frac14$

Comment: Note that the function can be rewritten as $x^3-(x-1)^3$, and since $x^3$ is monotonically increasing, this function is always positive.  (In fact, it is always $\geq 1/4$.)

Comment: well it is definitely not onto for real numbers, just equate $f(x)$ with say some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ then the function is onto if you can find a real root to $f(x) - y = 0$ for each $y$

Comment: Is there a typo in your query that might explain the conflict?  Did the problem actually **assert** that the function was **onto** with respect to all real #'s (for example) and ask you to prove this assertion, or did the problem simply ask you **whether** the function was onto all real numbers?  Alternatively, did the problem perhaps assert that the function was onto a **different** set, such as all positive #'s $\geq 1$?

Answer (score 5):

$$
\underbrace{ 3x^2 - 3x +1 = 3\left( x-\tfrac 1 2 \right)^2+ \tfrac 1 4}_\text{completing the square (without all the details)}
$$
As a mapping whose domain is $(-\infty,+\infty),$ this is onto the set $\left[\frac 1 4, +\infty \right).$ It is not onto $(-\infty,+\infty).$

Comment: nice mathJax...

Comment: @user2661923 : Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No quadratic polynomial is onto as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. The idea is that quadratics either "open up" or "open down", so they cannot map onto all of $\mathbb R$. For your specific example, can you find a negative number $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $3x^2-3x+1=a$ has no solutions for $x\in\mathbb R$? (Hint: think of the discriminant of this polynomial equation).

Comment: Well, I know that the discriminant is less that 0, so there are no values of x that will make the polynomial equal zero. how does that help me?

Comment: Well that works (in this case, $a=0$). You've shown that $3x^2-3x+1=0$ has no solutions, so $0$ is not in the image of $x\mapsto 3x^2-3x+1$. Hence, the image cannot be all of $\mathbb R$, so this map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is not surjective.